# Get status code from http.get

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to validate certain URLs based on their status code. I tried to do something like this:

```
const http = require('http');

let link = 'http://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100';

const getStatusCode = (link, callback) => {
    http.get(link, res => {
        callback(res.statusCode);
    })
}

const codeCallback = code => {
    console.log('Status code inside callback: ', code); //works, displays 301
    return code
}

let statusCode = getStatusCode(link, codeCallback)

console.log(statusCode) //undefined

if (statusCode) {...} //do something
```

Is there a way to store status code or should I implement validation logic inside callback?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the callback hell ;)

The way you're using it - yes, you need to do your validation logic inside the callback.

If you decide to explore this area further, I'd suggest looking promises and async/await in JavaScript.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a good example of a typical problem that arises when asynchronous calls happen in javascript. Specifically, the problem is that you are trying to print a variable before its value has been made available.

To explain more, all the http requests are asynchronous in nature due to the fact that they should not be blocking your application while you are waiting for a response from a server.

So when you are calling console.log(statusCode), this line gets executed before the http.get callback has been executed, so at the moment of execution the statusCode is undefined.

Indeed, the solution would be to handle the statusCode inside the callback. Something like this.

```
const http = require('http');

let link = 'http://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100';

const getStatusCode = (link, callback) => {
    http.get(link, res => {
        if (res.statusCode){
            callback(res.statusCode);
        }
    })
}

const codeCallback = code => {
    console.log('Status code inside callback: ', code); //works, displays 301
    return code
}

getStatusCode(link, codeCallback);
```

If you are interested in understanding how the whole asynchronous logic execution works here is a good intro https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ